# Arraylist - Using switch statement to add string

Tags: java, arraylist, switch-statement

I am new to programming and my professor has given an assignment that requires us to:

> "declare on arraylist with the size of 5. Use switch statement to add string values to your arraylist. Retrieve the contents of your arraylist. Check the size of each element. If the element length is less than 8 rerun the program, otherwise count the consonants of each element."

I've done some research to understand some factors of an `ArrayList`;
to start off, I did this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class izeOfArrayList {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();

    arrayList.add("1");
    arrayList.add("2");
    arrayList.add("3");

    int totalElements = arrayList.size();

    System.out.println("ArrayList contains...");
    for(int index=0; index < totalElements; index++)
      System.out.println(arrayList.get(index));

  }
}
```

This code just gets the number of elements currently stored in my `ArrayList`, and prints out each element.
I have three questions:

- **How can I add `String` values using `switch` statement?**
- How can I retrieve the contents of my `ArrayList`?
- How can I check the size of each element in my `ArrayList`?

Comment: You should declare `ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();` to get the *size* (I assume you mean length) of an element you can use `arrayList.get(index).length()`

Comment: Noted, and then? can you show me whats next I'm really confused about this question.

Comment: Yes length indeed.

Comment: By the way, apparently your entire class is stumped with this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36001856/arraylist-switch-statement

Comment: To retrieve the contents of the arraylist you could just System.out.print(list) or put it in a for loop and use System.out.print(list.get(index)) to output specific elements within the list, just like the for loop in your question...

Comment: `"Use switch statement to add string values to your arraylist."` <= Am I the only one who has a problem with this task? It seems senseless to me. At least it's underspecified.

Comment: Noted @KyhleOhlinger thanks!

Comment: @AndréStannek that is completely the case. There is no logic in the sentence `Use switch statement to add string values to your arraylist`.

Comment: @AndréStannek thats what gets me kinda confused

Comment: Ask your teacher then

Comment: I am assuming that my professor, wants us to use a string object in the expression of a switch statement. 

"Use switch statement to add string values to your arraylist"

Comment: Again, this makes no sense at all, read on [switch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) and see for yourself... The big question is *what* will you be *switching*...

Comment: @Villacampa yeah, but that's the issue we're having. that statement is meaningless, it provides no direction.

Comment: @Idos Thats the problem, we can't even ask any questions. We have to do it on our own. Any thanks for the concern

Comment: @Villacampa but this isn't a question to your professor akin to 'Please do this problem', this is a 'the entire might of stackoverflow has no idea what the problem is asking, can you please rephrase it?' type question

Comment: Even if you have to do it on our own your lecturer/teacher should provide you with a more detailed description

Comment: I am really confused

Comment: The question is already rephrased. @pandorym

Comment: I hope the teacher is not thinking of `switch (i) { case 0: arrayList.set(0, str); break; ...etc`.

Comment: I think not @trincot

Comment: ......................

Comment: @Villacampa when/where was the question rephrased? I don't see what you are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

> "declare on arraylist with the size of 5. Use switch statement to add string values to your arraylist. Retrieve the contents of your arraylist. Check the size of each element. If the element length is less than 8 rerun the program, otherwise count the consonants of each element."

Let's decode line by line:

> declare on arraylist with the size of 5.

```
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<>(5);
```

Our ArrayList needs to be defined as a list of `String`s, so we put those in the angle brackets. The constructor takes a starting size, which is specified as 5.

> Use switch statement to add string values to your arraylist.

Completely unintelligible. `switch` statements are used in flow of control; we can decide to add string values based on some condition, but we cannot generate input with `switch` statements, and no conditions are specified. This following code is (seemingly) valid for this instruction:

```
String values = "values";
switch (values) {
    case "values":
    default:
        myList.add(values);
}
```

> Retrieve the contents of your arraylist.

This you have already (mostly) written up:

```
int totalElements = myList.size();

for(int index = 0; index < totalElements; index++)
    String tempElem = myList.get(index); //get access to the individual elem

    //here we're going to do something with the current string (probably)

}
```

> Check the size of each element.

I'm assuming that by the *'size of each element'*, your professor is looking for the length of each `String`.

```
int tempElemLength = tempElem.length();
```

`String` objects have a length method, it returns an `int`.

> If the element length is less than 8 rerun the program, otherwise count the consonants of each element.

This, while at first glace seems reasonable, is again unintelligible. Here's a possible interpretation of this line:

```
if (tempElemLength < 8) {
    main(null);
} else {
    int tempElemNumConsonants = countConsonants(tempElem);

    //consonants are counted and now what?
}
```

Here is a complete response to your assignment as it is currently defined:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SizeOfArrayList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<>(5);

        String values = "values";
        switch (values) {
            case "values":
            default:
                myList.add(values);
        }

        int totalElements = myList.size();

        for (int index = 0; index < totalElements; index++)
            String tempElem = myList.get(index);

            int tempElemLength = tempElem.length();

            if (tempElemLength < 8) {
                main(null);
            } else {
                int tempElemNumConsonants = countConsonants(tempElem);

                //consonants are counted and now what?
                //guess print them out?
                System.out.println('Item ' + index + ': ' + tempElem + ' -> number of consonants: ' + tempElemNumConsonants);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is a solution to your problem *as it has been provided*; I will bet money that this is not the solution to your homework problem.

---

**In another school of thought**, if the focus of the assignment is basic use and understanding of `ArrayList`s and I was your professor, the assignment that I would have *intended* to give my students would be as follows:

> Declare and ArrayList with the size of 5. Prompt the user for values until they enter 'quit'; use a switch statement to add all `String` values into the ArrayList that aren't just a number from [0-9]. Loop over each element in the ArrayList; if the length of any `String` element is less than 8, alert the user then restart the program. If all of the lengths are valid, sum up the consonants of each element. Print out each word and the consonant count, along with a final tally of the number of words along with the total number of consonants.

While I do know that this does not help you with the initial question, I hope it might be able to help you understand what your professor is trying to ask of you.

Comment: This is totally a big help for me, you are my eye opener to my problems! Thanks! I partially get it one by one based on what you did. I seriously don't know what my professor wants but this surely helps me. Now, I have different conclusions to study on. Thanks!

Comment: You're very welcome, hopefully that'll get you started on the right track! Be sure to talk to your professor to clarify some of those things if you get a chance.

Comment: Also, be sure to accept my answer if you feel it answered your question! =D